# Compare the same array Java and input result in other array

Tags: java

I'm trying to commpare elements of array a. If it was the same, I type "1" in array b for this indexes. Else I type "0":

```
 public static void theSameValues(){
    int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 2};
    int[] b = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      for (int  j= i +1; j < a.length; j++){
            if (a[i] != a[j]){
               b[j] = 0;
               b[i] = 0;


          }
           else b[j] = 1;
               b[i] = 1;
     }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

the resul is wrong: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0].

Please, help to understand and resolve.

Comment: What do you mean by "same?" Do you mean the element is not unique?

Comment: your `b[i] = 1;` is unconditional

Comment: "Please resolve for me" what a sentence, maybe share the expected result and clarify the text first

Comment: your second loop starts from 1 not 0 so you are comparing a[0] and b[1] ...

Comment: @JosefProcházka there's no comparison involving `b`, they're just avoiding comparing with previous elements and the current element itself

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 public static void theSameValues(){

    int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 1, 3, 2};

   //you can initialize this by a function
   int[] b = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      for (int  j= i +1; j < a.length; j++){
         if (a[i] == a[j]){
            b[j] = 1;
            b[i] = 1;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? What did you change? Why?

Comment: Array 'b' is initialize to 0's as default values. Which means initially no numbers are same. Within the for loop, array 'a' is checked for same numbers and if numbers are same, then change that indexes of array 'b' to 1.